# Random number of divs with random number of elements with PHP

Tags: php, random, for-loop

I need to generate random number of divs with five items per div (and remaining items in the last div) from random number of $totalItems and also not all the items satisfy $OKItems... Hopefully the code explains better than me.

My problem is that this script generates empty divs with no content in them.

```
<?php

  $OKItems = 0;
  $totalItems = rand(2,30);

  for ($i = 0; $i < $totalItems; $i++) { 
    echo ($OKItems == 0 || $OKItems % 5 == 0) ? 'div open<br />' : '';

    $testValue = rand(0, 1);
    if ($testValue != 0) {
      echo '1'; 
      $OKItems++;
    }

    echo ($OKItems % 5 == 0 || $i+1 == $totalItems) ? '<br />div close<br />' : '';
  } 

?>
```

This is what I might get:

```
div open

div close
div open
11111
div close
div open

div close
div open

div close
div open
11
div close
```

And this is what I would have wanted in this case:

```
div open
11111
div close
div open
11
div close
```

Comment: Please choose one of the given answers and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

const N = 5;
$totalItems = rand(2,30);

$items = array() ;
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalItems; $i++) { 
    $testValue = rand(0, 1);
    if ($testValue != 0) {
      $items[] = 1 ;
    }

    if( N == sizeof($items) || (($i == $totalItems - 1) && 0 < sizeof($items))  ) {
        echo "<div>" . join(",", $items) . "</div>";
        $items = array() ;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ajreal I've tested the code, and you should do it too, before posting comments. You may add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` after `<?php`, if you still think it would not work.

Comment: @St.Woland - `const` only for class, not in procedural

Comment: Thank you, I went this solution as it was easiest to implement into my existing actual code.

Comment: @ajreal ok sorry make it clearer next time. I used `const` for ease of understanding, not for markup. You may use `define` or even variables in a real-world application.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a bit more structure to your code.

My approach would be to break it up into several stages, as opposed to trying to do all the logic in the loop that outputs data.

**What I'd suggest:**

1. Decide how many items to be tested
2. Test each item and only copy the ones that pass into a new array
3. Partition this new array into sets of 5
4. Output each partition as a div

**Code (untested):**

```
// Decide how many items to test
$totalItems = rand(2,30);

// Test these items and add them to an accepted array
$items = Array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalItems; $i++) { 
  $testValue = rand(0, 1);
  if ($testValue != 0) { $items[] = "1" }
}

//Partition them into sections
$partitions = array_chunk($items,5);

//Output as divs
foreach($partitions as $partition):
  echo 'div open <br />';
    foreach($partition as $item):
      echo $item . "<br />";
    endforeach;
  echo 'div close <br />';
endforeach;
```

When you split up the code into logical steps, it becomes much easier to maintain and debug.

Comment: Thank you for a nice answer. This would have worked, but @St.Woland gave solution that was easier to implement into my actual existing code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$OKItems = 0;
$totalItems = rand(2,30);

for ($i = 0; $i < $totalItems; $i++) { 
  echo ($OKItems == 0 || $OKItems % 5 == 0) ? 'div open<br>' : '';

  $testValue = rand(0, 1);
  if ($testValue != 0) {
    echo '1'; 
    $OKItems++;
  }

  if($OKItems % 5 == 0 || $i+1 == $totalItems) {
      echo '<br>div close<br>';
      $OKItems = 0;
  }
} 

?>
```

That should be working ;)

I changed your check line for an if function that also resets your $OKItems. The problem you had (i think) was that you got a 0 as the random value and that would keep $OKitems on 5.

Comment: Tested this briefly and this also made empty divs. Thank you anyway - at least my problem got solved. :)